# Pasar valores de un Dropdown a otro Flutter

Tags: flutter

Estoy creando una App usando flutter, y tengo el siguiente problema: En una screen tengo un Dropdown donde selecciono un país, al seleccionarlo el guarda los prefijos de ese pais en una lista, la idea es esa lista pasarla a un segundo Dropdown donde se mostraran los prefijos acorde al pais seleccionado:

```
class _CountriesViewState extends ConsumerState {
    
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        final countriesState = ref.watch(countriesProvider);
        String? _selectedCountryIso;
        String? _selectedPrefix;
        List<String> selectedCountryPrefixes = [];
        final List<String> countryNames = countriesState.countries.map((country) => country.countryName).toList();
        return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 18.0),
            child: Form(
                child: Column(
                    children: [
                        CustomDropdown(
                            labelText: 'País',
                            items: countryNames,
                            value: _selectedCountryIso,
                            onSelectionChanged: (newValue) {
                                setState(() {
                                    selectedCountryPrefixes = countriesState.countries
                                    .firstWhere((country) => country.countryName == newValue)
                                    .prefix
                                    .map((prefix) => prefix['Prefix']!)
                                    .toList();
                                });
                                print("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@");
                                print(selectedCountryPrefixes);
                                print("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@");
                                //HASTA ACA TODO BIEN, CARGAN LOS PAISES Y EN selectedCountryPrefixes ESTAN LOS PREFIJOS, EJEMPLO: [1201, 1202, 1203, 1205, 1206]
                            },
                            onChanged: (newValue) {},
                        ),
                        CustomDropdown(
                            labelText: 'Prefijo',
                            items: selectedCountryPrefixes,
                            value: _selectedPrefix,
                            //EN ESTE DROPDOWN NO CARGA NADA :(
                            onSelectionChanged: (newValue) {
            
                            },
                            onChanged: (newValue) {},
                        ),
```

Como comente en el código el primer Dropdown funciona bien carga los países y almacena los prefijos en selectedCountryPrefixes  de esta forma [1201, 1202, 1203, 1205, 1206].

He trabado de hacer por un lado y por otro pero en el segundo Dropdown no se cargan los prefijos, agradezco enormemente su colaboración.